# Could not find Fragment constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing the issue on some devices and getting an error on my crash analytics. A lot of user devices are facing this issue, but on my device it's working fine.

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ox.outloks.new/com.ox.outloks.new.activities.MainDrawerActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.alchemative.outfitters.outfitters.fragments.ProductsFragment: could not find Fragment constructor

The error is coming at the line which is in activity **super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Here is ProductsFragment constructor

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public ProductsFragment(String id) {
    categoryID = id;
}
```

Comment: What does your `ProductsFragment` class look like? Do you have any special constructors in it?

Comment: @BenP. I have updated my question, yes I have special constructor

Comment: @BenP. beat me to it. On another note, make sure you have a default empty constructor (dont override the default constructor), fragments need one. Also you should have a static method (newInstance) defined in that fragment that takes params...

Comment: "Don't keep activities" developer setting helps replicate this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668934/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-for-oncreate

Answer (score 229, accepted):

All `Fragment` classes you create **must** have a public, no-arg constructor. In general, the best practice is to simply never define any constructors at all and rely on Java to generate the default constructor for you. But you could also write something like this:

```
public ProductsFragment() {
    // doesn't do anything special
}
```

If your fragment needs extra information, like `String id` in your posted example, a common pattern is to define a `newInstance()` static "factory method" that will use the arguments `Bundle` to give that info to your fragment.

```
public static ProductsFragment newInstance(String id) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", id);
    ProductsFragment f = new ProductsFragment();
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

Now, rather than calling `new ProductsFragment(id)`, you'll call `ProductsFragment.newInstance(id)`. And, inside your fragment, you can access the id by calling `getArguments().getString("id")`.

By leveraging the arguments bundle (instead of creating a special constructor), your fragment will be able to be destroyed and recreated by the Android framework (e.g. if the user rotates their phone) and your necessary info (the id) will persist.

Comment: I have already done this but still, I am getting the error - Issue: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blipclap.wallpaper/com.blipclap.wallpaper.HomeActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.blipclap.wallpaper.Fragment.RecentsFragment: could not find Fragment constructor

Comment: What if I need to pass Object variable (likely FrameLayout) as extra information ? cuz I don't see any way to put it into Bundle instance.

Comment: I have a fragment with no argument in constrructor and yet facing the exact problem, what can be wrong ? i probably should mention that i open my app after a while when Process Death occurred.

Comment: I would suggest  adding a Public constructor with a comment `//Required empty public constructor`. It is to tell others that this empty public constructor is needed or else people do tend to make the constructor private as there is a public `getInstance()` factory method.

Answer (score 13):

Accepted answer is not entirely correct as of today. With [FragmentFactory](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/android-fragmentfactory-75823af015fd)

you can create fragment such as

```
MyFragment(arg1:Any, arg2:Any,...) {

}
```

and instantiate it inside FragmentFactory's instantiate method

```
override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment {

        return when (className) {
            MyFragment::class.java.name -> MyFragment(arg1, arg2)
            
        }

    }
```

and set your FragmentFactory as supportFragmentManager's fragment factory before **onCreate** of Activity, because Android checks out for empty constructor fragment and if you don't provide before onCreate your app will crash as usual behavior.

```
supporFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = yourFragmentFactoryInstance
```

Comment: This should be also accepted. You can set `supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory` in your activity's onCreate before the `super.onCreate` call

Answer (score 6):

A newer alternative to communicate between an Activity and a Fragment, thus allowing that the Fragment can have an empty constructor would be the use of [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from below method of fragment class that basically shows how we should basically do initialisation of our fragment classes in general. First see that method below:-

```
public static Fragment instantiate(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String fname,
        @Nullable Bundle args) {
    try {
        Class<? extends Fragment> clazz = FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(
                context.getClassLoader(), fname);
        Fragment f = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        if (args != null) {
            args.setClassLoader(f.getClass().getClassLoader());
            f.setArguments(args);
        }
        return f;
    } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
        throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                + " empty constructor that is public", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                + " empty constructor that is public", e);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                + ": could not find Fragment constructor", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                + ": calling Fragment constructor caused an exception", e);
    }
}
```

So if you will see problem lies with **catch (NoSuchMethodException e)** code block which triggers in this case since its not able detect contructor of the fragment from line **Fragment f = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();**. If you will see the function **getConstructor()**, You will observe this will reponsible to make this exception since it throws this **NoSuchMethodException** and same have caught inside **Fragment instantiate** funtion. Also if you move further on above function the recommended approach for sending params to a fragment arguments is also given. So now we are all clear about what to do.

1. To send data into fragment we should make instance/static function of that receiver fragment, and put all required params into this.
2. Then put data using fragment arguments into receiver fragment within instance function.
3. Finally just get those arguments into **onCreate/onCreateView**.

**Note: This Fragment class was deprecated in API level 28.**
**Use the** [Jetpack Fragment Library Fragment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) **for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.**

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the fragment class is public as well

Comment: Hey It may be good to explain why it's importatnt to have public constructor

Comment: ...to have a public class.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar case with a modal (FragmentDialog).

**Replicate steps:**

1. The modal is showed.
2. Do not close modal.
3. Put the App in background and open another Apps.
4. Keep in background for a long time.
5. When return to App, Android tries reopen the modal because the Android System recicles the memory.
6. The App crash.

Also can replicate its from Android Developer mode, we need change the Background process limit to "No background process"

**Solution (With Kotlin)**.

- Option 1: Use Bundle for pass args.
- Option 2: Use Fragment factory.
- Option 3: Initialize the params with values default.

```
class ProductsFragment(id: String = "") {
      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced this exception. My mistake was calling `requireArguments()` method before arguments were received by the Fragment

Answer (score 1):

I just putted this overrided onCreate inside Myfragment, that extends Fragment. And it works. But i think, it's kind of a plug.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyFragment.newInstance();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    super.onCreate(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen if you call requireContext() method before onCreate() of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your Fragment's constructor. In some cases it could be marked like `private` and system can't use it during restore state operation and you'll get a crash. Just use simple test with `Don't keep activities` option from `Developer options` to confirm system able to restore your fragment properly.