# How to pass data from BaseAdapter to AppCompatDialogFragment? Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass data from my FoodAdapter which exteds from BaseAdapter to FoodDialog which extends from AppCompatDialogFragment. I need to pass the data to FoodDialog when the user clicks on button in the list_item.

```
addToCart = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        View finalConvertView = convertView;
        addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(position));
                TextView s = (TextView) finalConvertView.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
                ConfirmFoodDialog confirmFoodDialog = new ConfirmFoodDialog();

                confirmFoodDialog.show(((CategoryMenu) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Title");

                Intent intent = new Intent(finalConvertView.getContext(), ConfirmFoodDialog.class);
                intent.putExtra("Dish", s.getText().toString()); // s.getText().toString() returns the desired value
                
                
            }
```

ConfirmFoodDialog.class

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyCustomTheme);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        food = intent.getStringExtra("Dish"); // food is a String variable
        System.out.println(food); // I don't know why food returns null
}
```

Comment: `confirmFoodDialog.show(((CategoryMenu) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Title");` here you're showing the dialog, then later

           `Intent intent = new Intent(finalConvertView.getContext(), ConfirmFoodDialog.class);
                intent.putExtra("Dish", s.getText().toString()); // s.getText().toString() returns the desired value` you're building an intent which is doing nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are showing your dialog with `show(FragmentManager)`, it seems like your dialog is a subclass of `DialogFragment`. If this is the case, then you pass information to it the same way you pass information to any `Fragment`: via the `arguments` `Bundle`.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Dish", s.getText().toString());

ConfirmFoodDialog confirmFoodDialog = new ConfirmFoodDialog();
confirmFoodDialog.setArguments(args);
confirmFoodDialog.show(((CategoryMenu) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Title");
```

To read the value out from within the fragment, access the `arguments` and read your information:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ...

    food = getArguments().getString("Dish");
    System.out.println(food);
}
```

You can simplify the first part by [implementing the `newInstance()` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51831137/8298909) for your DialogFragment.