# App crashes on theme changed when bottom sheet is opened

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have a bottom sheet which I inflate to display a restaurant product detailed information.

```
class ProductItemInfo(private val product: Product) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: DialogProductInfoBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = DialogProductInfoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.apply {
            productName.text = product.name
            productPrice.text = String.format("Rs %s", product.totalPrice)
            productCategory.text=product.category
            productDescription.text=product.category
            productImage.load(product.image)
        }
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

I inflate this bottom sheet dialog from a fragment.

```
val dialogProductInfoBinding = ProductItemInfo(it)
dialogProductInfoBinding.show(childFragmentManager, null)
```

The problem is when I open the bottom sheet and then drag my notification shade to toggle the dark theme, my application crashes. I have no idea why is it happening.

Here is the error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ass.cafeburp.dine, PID: 18522
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ass.cafeburp.dine/ass.cafeburp.dine.presentation.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in ass.cafeburp.dine:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in ass.cafeburp.dine:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:6347)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:6212)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in ass.cafeburp.dine:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in ass.cafeburp.dine:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in ass.cafeburp.dine:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ass.cafeburp.dine.presentation.dialogs.ProductItemInfo: could not find Fragment constructor
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:678)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:498)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:81)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveStateInternal(FragmentManager.java:2496)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1989)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1965)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1965)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1267)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at ass.cafeburp.dine.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:49)
        at ass.cafeburp.dine.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:43)
        at ass.cafeburp.dine.presentation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4009)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:6347)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:6212)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ass.cafeburp.dine.presentation.dialogs.ProductItemInfo.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1759)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:663)
            ... 56 more
```

Comment: What was the error!?

Comment: Add your log details... If it's related to the theme then include your theme as well

Comment: @GobuCSG I have added the error logs. Please check.

Comment: Create an empty constructor in you bottom sheet... More Info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831053/could-not-find-fragment-constructor

Comment: @GobuCSG That does work but now I had to pass null in the constructor and dismiss the bottomsheetdialog. Is there any way I can keep it open?

Comment: You can create multiple constructor... Are you aware!? And whatever you want you can pass it via bundle as well...

Comment: @GobuCSG yes I am aware I can create multiple constructors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246529/discussion-between-ankit-verma-and-gobu-csg).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue earlier...

The solution that worked for me is...

1. The bottomsheet's constructor arguments must have default values assigned.
2. then check for that values under onViewCreated{} method of bottomsheetdialogfragment. If they are default values, then call `this.dismiss()`

this is my constructor

```
class BottomSheetFragment(
    private val matchDetailsList: List<Matchlist_Model> = emptyList() ,
    private val matchPosition: Int = -1
) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {}
```

And calling dismiss() like below.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if ((matchPosition == -1) or matchDetailsList.isEmpty()){
            this.dismiss()
        }
}
```